crear campo calculado que sume 1 al mismo campo del registro anterior SQL
Imaginemos que tengo base de datos
Campos: 
Producto, vendido, diasnoven
Registro 1
Lana,   Si,    0
Registro 2
Lana.   No.    1
Registro 3
Lana.   Si     0
Registro 4
Lana.   No.    1
Registro 5
Lana.   No.    2

Lo que necesito es que cada día que no se venda lana, mire si el día anterior tampoco se vendió y en ese caso que sume 1 al valor de ese mismo campo calculado del día anterior o si se vende en un nuevo día, pinta el valor 0 en el campo DiasNoVen.
Si utilizo la función Lag() puedo visualizar el valor del día anterior, pero no se cómo sumarle a ese valor 1, ni tampoco crear la fórmula para que en lugar de mostrarlo, que actualice ese campo en todos los registros.
Espero vuestra ayuda.
Gracias
Lo estoy intentando hacer en management studio

puedes mostrar el codigo de lo que dices que estas intentando hacer (Edita y agregalo al post)???

¿Cómo sabes cual es el orden de las filas? ¿Cuál manejador de base de datos estás usando? Cada manejador tiene una sintaxis distinta a pesar de estar basádos en un estándar.

A esa tabla le haría falta un campo fecha para poder hacerlo.

Bills jachguate. Gracias por TU interés. He estado liado con temas personales y no he podido contestar antes. En cuanto esté delante del pc te envío estructura de tabla, pero si que tiene un campo fecha. Lo estoy manejando en Mannagement Studio con SQL Server
